# WordPress plugin not installing(instagram-auto-poster)

Tags: wordpress

I want to install instagram-auto-poster but it shows error in these lines:

```
      $data = [
      'phone_id'            => $this->generateUUID(true),
      '_csrftoken'          => $token[0],
      'username'            => $this->username,
      'guid'                => $this->uuid,
      'device_id'           => $this->device_id,
      'password'            => $this->password,
      'login_attempt_count' => '0',
  ];

      $login = $this->request('accounts/login/', $this->generateSignature(json_encode($data)), true);

      if ($login[1]['status'] == 'fail') {
          throw new InstagramException($login[1]['message']);

          return;
      }
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: What is the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/itarfand/public_html/wp-content/plugins/instagram-auto-poster/instagram-api/Instagram.php on line 86